# Limit with condition $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(x) n^x\right) =1,x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits

Suppose I have the following limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(x) n^x\right) =1,x\in \mathbb{R}
$$

What is condition for $x$ to ensure equality?

My attemp.

Сonsider when the expression
$n^x=const$, then $x=0$, then put $x=0$ to $f(x)$ and check that $f(x)=1$.

For example
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\cos(x) n^x\right) =1
$$

Put $x=0$ to $\cos(x)$, we get $\cos(0)=1$, then it's true that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\cos(x) n^x\right) =1,x=0
$$

I understand that
$$
f(x) \lim_{n\to \infty }\left(n^x\right) =1
$$
And
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(n^x\right) = \frac{1}{f(x)}
$$

But I doubt the validity of it. What if $f(x)$ has a pole for some $x$ and tends to zero and $n^x$ for some $x$ tends to infinity?

If it generally true, how to strict proof that?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this: you must impose conditions on $x$ and on $f$.

I suppose $f(x)$ is a real number and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, you are asking 
$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty }  n^x  = 1/f(x)
$$
If $x=0$ the limit is $1$, so you must also impose that $f(0)=1$.
If $x>0$ the limit is divergent, so (loosely speaking) you must impose that $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$. If $x<0$ the limit is $0$, so (even more loosely speaking) you must impose that $f(x)=\infty$ for $x<0$. As you can see your request does not make much sense, because it forces you to consider a very particular form of $f$ that is not even well defined everywhere.

Comment: If $x=1/n$ and $f$ is continuous at 0 with f(0)=1,still the equality in OP holds.

Comment: But $x$ is a parameter to be fixed before taking the limit. Usually in this kind of problems you do not consider parameters to have a dependence on $n$ itself, otherwise they are not "parameters" anymore.